# Cannot convert the value of '{!dateValue}' to the expected type

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am looking to use the below component in the VF Page dyanamically, but its not working and giving the below error

```
Cannot convert the value of '{!dateValue}' to the expected type.
```

in the VF Page I am simply using

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="Object__c == obj}">
    <apex:outputPanel >
        <div>
            {!m2.ELC_FieldLabel__c}
            <apex:outputText value="{!objectTestMap[obj][m2.FieldNameAPI__c]}"/>
            <div class="{!IF($ObjectType[obj].Fields[m2.FieldNameAPI__c].Type=='date','show','hide')}">
                <c:LocaleDateComponent date_Value="{!objectTestMap[obj][m2.FieldNameAPI__c]}" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </apex:outputPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
```

Component for reference.

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="DateController">
<apex:attribute assignTo="{!dateValue}" 
                description="The Date value to be rendered based upon the user's locale" 
                name="date_Value" 
                type="Date">
</apex:attribute>
       {!TimeZoneValue}
</apex:component>
```

Here is the controller code

```
public class DateController {
    public Date dateValue {get; set;}
    public Datetime dateTimeValue {get; set;}

    public String getTimeZoneValue(){

        Map<String, String> localeValues = getLocaleMapValues();

        //Get the locale of the user
        String userlocale = UserInfo.getLocale(); 
        if(localeValues.containsKey(userlocale)){
            dateformat = localeValues.get(userlocale);
        }   

        if(dateValue != null)
            return DateTime.newInstance(dateValue.year(), dateValue.month(), dateValue.day()).format(dateformat);
        else
            return dateTimeValue.format(dateformat);
    }

    public Map<String, String> getLocaleMapValues() {
        Map<String, String> locale_map = new Map<String, String>(); 
        locale_map.put('en_US', 'MM/dd/yyyy'); 
        return locale_map;
    }   
}
```

Is this Date value Sat Dec 30 00:00:00 GMT 2017 or DateTime ?

Comment: here `date_Value="{!objectTestMap[obj][m2.FieldNameAPI__c]}"` what is the type of `{!objectTestMap[obj][m2.FieldNameAPI__c]}` ?

Comment: I think if  we look at Sat Dec 30 00:00:00 GMT 2017, looks like this is not Date, is is gregorian Date ?

Comment: so whatever it is type based on that change into the component